# Whats the PGP key for custom connectors for

Tags: unificationengine

During the creation of a custom connector the unificationengine asks me for a PGP public key, but I can't find any usage for this key in the documentation. What is this key meant for and how do I have to implement it's usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PGP public key is used for encrypting the credentials.
Now we have implemented encryption only in sending messages with non reusable credentials (storing the Id/ Secret/Access token within the client app and not within Unification engine) . 
In the near future we will focus our efforts of full fledged encryption, to prepare the connectors for this scenario we have made it mandatory while creating a connector.
You can write the connector without using encryption but while creating the connector in Unification Engine you have to provide a pgp public key.
You can generate the pgp keys using https://pgpkeygen.com/. You need to save the private key for decrypting the data if you are encrypting the credentials.
As of now documentation is provided only for connectors with reusable credentials. 
If you are planning to create the connector with non reusable credential please let us know we will provide you with detailed explanation.

Comment: OK thanks for the clarification. Are there any special reasons why PGP was chosen over a standard transport encryption with TLS/SSL?

Comment: PGP allows an even more secure transfer of encrypted data between the application and the respective connector. PGP encryption ensures that wherever UnificationEngine is hosted, that provider cannot read the data transferred. Only the developer of the application can and theoretically whoever hosts the connector, could.